# Does OCA module report_qweb_element_page_visibility leave blank spaces in Odoo 15?

Tags: xml, odoo, qweb, odoo-15

In Odoo 15, I am modifying the PDF reports in order to show some info in the header at the first page, and other different info at the left pages.

To do that, I use a existing OCA module, very popular, named **report_qweb_element_page_visibility**. Once installed, if you set to elements classes like `first-page` or `not-first-page`, it applies the style `display: none;` to them depending on the page they are.

The problem is that `display: none;` does not hide the elements fully. They still occupy space, for example, if I have a `div` with a long text which has a height of 5 cm, I see 5 cm of blank space, which obviously looks awful:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="first-page" name="left_block">
            FIRST PAGE LEFT
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" name="right_block">
        <div class="first-page">
            FIRST PAGE RIGHT
        </div>
        <div class="not-first-page">
            OTHER PAGE RIGHT
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the previous example, at the very first page, *FIRST PAGE RIGHT* has a blank space below it. And at the left pages, *OTHER PAGE RIGHT* has the blank space above it. In this example is only a line, but the more info you add, the bigger the blank space is.

Does anybody experience this? Could anybody give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the `Wkhtmltopdf` library version. With the right one, the elements with `display: none;` do not leave blank spaces.